# Printing out 1 to n recursively

Tags: java, recursion

I have a task to print out numbers 1 to 5 recursively. I have done the following and it works but I am  getting a java.lang.StackOverflowError in console. Should this be expected or could I handle it better?

```
   package main;

   import java.util.ArrayList;

   public class Recursion {

    public static void printNumbersRecursively(){
        int [] a = new int [10];
        a[0]=1;//initialization  
        a[1]=2;  
        a[2]=3;  
        a[3]=4;  
        a[4]=5;  

        for(int i=0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
        printNumbersRecursively();
    }


   public static void main(String[] args){
      printNumbersRecursively();
 }
  }
```

Comment: `I have done the following` - please include your code in the question

Comment: Your implementation is incorrect, and that is the cause of the exceptions.   For a start, there should NOT be a `for` or `while` or `do while` loop in a recursive solution.  And you don't need an array.  And you shouldn't hard code the number 5 into your recursive method.  I suggest you *review* your lecture notes on recursion, and understand the examples that you have (presumably) been given there.

Comment: additional note: you are getting StackOverflow because there is no condition terminating the recursion, that is, the method is calling itself for ever (or until the stack (aka memory) overflows)

Answer (score 0):

use something like this:

```
    public static void printnumber(int i){
        if(i<0) return;
        System.out.println(i);
        printnumber(i-1);
    }
```

and in main:

```
printnumber(5);
```

the reason you are getting that stackOverflow error?
you are calling a function in itself and there is no Control on when to finish this loop! so this recursive call repeats till the CPU gets full, and boom.

also i advice you to learn more about recursive functions, because it seems you don't know its basics :)

Answer (score 0):

The question is somewhat usefull and I couldn't find an immediate duplicate so here you go:

```
public static void printNumbersRecursively(int n) {
    if (n > 0)
        printNumbersRecursively(n - 1);
    else
        return;
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

Just call from main with `printNumbersRecursively(5);`

Answer (score 0):

The question did specify to recursively print from 1 to n. So, this function will print from `1` to `5` when calling it with `printNumbersRecursively(1, 5)`.

```
public static void printNumbersRecursively(int i, int n) {
    System.out.println(i);
    if (i < n)
        printNumbersRecursively(i + 1, n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The recursive solutions should have a boundary condition, Otherwise, there will be no termination. Eventually, it will create a StackOverflowError.

```
  package main;

   import java.util.ArrayList;

   public class Recursion {

    public static void printNumbersRecursively(int i, int n){
        if(i<=n) {
          System.out.println(i);
          printNumbersRecursively(i+1, n);
        }
        return;
    }


   public static void main(String[] args){
      printNumbersRecursively(1, 5);
 }
  }
```

Termination condition will be `i<=n`. `i` will be in a range from 1 to `n`(In your case 5).